# My if and else statement keeps evaluating as false but it is true in Python

Tags: python

my dictionary nested in a list

```
coins = [
{"Ethereum": "ETH-USD",
 "Bitcoin": "BIT-USD",
 "Solona": "SOL-USD"}
]
```

my function

```
def new():

search = input('Enter a coin\n').capitalize()
querystring = {"q": " ", "hl": "en", "gl": "US"}
if search not in coins:
    print('Please enter a valid coin')
else:
    querystring["q"] = search
```

my input is in the list but for some reason its coming back false and returning

```
print('Please enter a valid coin')
```

for some odd reason when I do

```
if search **in** coins:
    print('Please enter a valid coin')
else:
    querystring["q"] = search
```

I get the result I am looking for but that is because it is still evaluating as false at the start of the if statement. I feel like I am over looking something small or my knowledge on if and else statements might be a little flawed because I have this issue often when writing if and else statements.

Comment: What do you think `search not in coins` does?

Comment: looks in coins and checks if the value for search is found by evaluating to True or False.

Comment: And what value are you searching for? And what values actually exist in `coins`?

Comment: the input I am expecting from the users is one of the keys in the dictionary, which holds a value which is a ticker symbol that needs to be plugged into the querystring inorder to get the right results from the api

Comment: then you need to compare against the keys in the dictionary rather than elements of a list. Sounds like you don't need a list at all, and then the `in` comparision will work the way you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
coins = [
{"Ethereum": "ETH-USD",
 "Bitcoin": "BIT-USD",
 "Solona": "SOL-USD"}
]
```

Here you declare a list which contains a dictionary. When you do `x in coins`, if `x` is a string, then the expression will always be false because `coins` only contains a dictionary, not a string. A string can never be equal to a dictonary.

To fix this, remove the brackets `[]`, so that you only have a dictionary rather than a list with a dictionary.

Comment: this worked for me, so if I wore to have a dictionary nested in a dictionary or multiple dictionaries in `coins` would it still evaluate to false because `search` is a string `coins` contains a dictionary within a dictionary or multiple dictionaries which is the actual value of `coins` ? hope that makes sense

Comment: @drafty It is difficult to answer your question from a description of code rather than directly from actual code. I suggest you read more about how lists, dictionaries, and `in` work. I'll just say that if `coins` is a dictionary, rather than a list, then `in` will compare against the keys in the dictionary.

Comment: how exactly would I search to see if the users input is in the dictonary above and if so take the value associated with the key and plug it into the querystring. I may need to open a new question for this but ultimatly this script is a test for a function I will be adding to my Django web app.

Comment: @drafty What "dictionary above"? `coins` in your original question is a list, not a dictionary. If it were a dictionary, then the `in` keyword would work. Beyond that I can't help without any actual code. Feel free to post a new question.